# How to push results from map to multiple list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have the same operation from two list and want to put them in one map function rather than two.

```
        val messages1 = list.map {
            spConverter.mapToSppmFromPs(it)
        }
        val messages2 = list.map {
            spConverter.mapToSpFromPs(it)
        }
```

Is there a way to put this two operation into one map?

Comment: do you still want `messages1` and `messages2` as two different list? or do you want those in single list?

Comment: I still want them seperately

Comment: Why do you want them in one map function? Do you want your code to be as short as possible, or do you think it'll perform better, or what? (And what exactly do you mean by ‘in one map function’ — one occurrence of `map` in your code, or one invocation at runtime, or something else?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map` function can only create one list, so you can't have it create `messages1` and `messages2` which are two lists. Perhaps this code will suit:

```
val (messages1, messages2) = list
    .map { Pair(spConverter.mapToSppmFromPs(it), spConverter.mapToSpFromPs(it)) }
    .unzip()
```

First, the `map` function creates a list of pairs, and then the unzip function runs over that list and creates the two lists that you want.

Unless your `list` is actually something that can only be iterated once, I would prefer your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really.

`.map` returns ONE result. So yes, you could have:

```
    val messages1 = mutableListOf()
    val messages2 = list.map {
        messages1.add(spConverter.mapToSppmFromPs(it))
        spConverter.mapToSpFromPs(it)
    }
```

But that is just ugly. I think running forEach somewhere in the code will be better.